# How to put a glyphicon between two jumbotrons?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

[image]

Basically I want to have the glyphicon in between the two jumbotrons. Here is my code. Not sure why the arrow goes into the next line or at the end of the jumbotrons.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron col-xs-2" style="padding: 10px; background-color:#4aca4a; color:white"><b>Step 1</b><br /> A company posts a project <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div>
    <div class="jumbotron col-xs-2 col-sm-offset-1" style="padding: 10px; background-color:#4aca4a; color:white"><b>Step 2</b><br /> Students apply for the project</div>

</div>
```

Comment: you want to have your icon in between, but why did you place your span in one of the jumbotron divs then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron col-xs-5" style="padding: 10px; background-color:#4aca4a; color:white"><b>Step 1</b><br /> A company posts a project </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div>
  <div class="jumbotron col-xs-5" style="padding: 10px; background-color:#4aca4a; color:white"><b>Step 2</b><br /> Students apply for the project</div>
</div>
```

If you want **vertical align** you have to add some flex

```css
.container.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container.flex .jumbotron {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container flex">
  <div class="jumbotron col-xs-5" style="padding: 10px; background-color:#4aca4a; color:white"><b>Step 1</b><br /> A company posts a project </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div>
  <div class="jumbotron col-xs-5" style="padding: 10px; background-color:#4aca4a; color:white"><b>Step 2</b><br /> Students apply for the project</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nenad's approach, but with static line height below. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/401xtb4p/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron col-xs-2 col-sm-3" style="padding: 10px; background-color:#4aca4a; color:white">
    <h3>Step 1</h3>
    <p>A company posts a project</p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-container col-xs-1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron col-xs-2 col-sm-3" style="padding: 10px; background-color:#4aca4a; color:white">
    <h3>Step 2</h3>
    <p>Students apply for the project</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.arrow-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow-container .glyphicon {
  color: #4aca4a;
  line-height: 6;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

**Update**
If your jumbotrons will always be on the same row, I would go with using display: table on the containers and display: table-cell on the inner container so that the arrow can be set to **vertical-align: middle**. Another dynamic approach would be move the glyphicon over into the last jumbotron and set it's position to absolute and move its left to 0 and top to 45%;